# MOSFET is not turning off when the gate terminal is grounded

Tags: power-supply, mosfet, switch-mode-power-supply, bjt

This figure shows a small portion of my circuit:

[image]

The maximum Vgs of the MOSFET is 20V. The MOSFET is initially turned on and now I want to turn it off. For that I am grounding the terminal A to ground through a resistor of 1k. But it is not turning off. If I do this without the 1k resistor it is turning off. What could be the possible reason?

Comment: Just for curiosity's sake (I'm not an expert): isn't your NMOS a _depletion-mode_ NMOS? In [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MOSFET#Circuit_symbols) it appears that the symbol you are using refers to this type of transistor, which is practically the _opposite_ of a regular enhanced-mode NMOS (off for VGS > VT, on for VGS< VT)

Comment: @FiatLux I am using <www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/2N7002.pdf>. I have drawn the above figure in LTSpice.

Comment: OK, nevermind, your transistor is a regular enhancement mode NFET. It was just the circuit symbol that confused me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you attach A to ground, you have, in effect, this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ftUos3.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Since the gate current of a MOSFET can be assumed to be zero, we can think of this as a [voltage divider](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage_divider), and see that the voltage at the gate of M1 is 2.7V. This isn't low enough to turn the transistor off.

Probably, you want to remove R6, or make its value very much less. A MOSFET, unlike a BJT, has a very high gate impedance, and so does not require a resistor to limit the current.

Answer (score 3):

The resistors attached to the gate form a voltage divider. If the 1k is floating, you have 10/25 of 48V on the gate, or 19.2V. If the 1k is pulled to common, you have .9/15.9 of 48V on the gate, or 2.7V. Depending on the FET, that 2.7V may be enough to keep it on.

If the 1k resistor is absent, you're pulling the gate directly to common, which will certainly turn it off (barring noise and the like). Basically, your 1k resistor is too big.

Comment: .. or R1, R2, R3 are too small.

Answer (score 2):

The answer should really be obvious.  Just look at what the voltage is on the gate when A is held at ground.  You have a resistor divider with (7.5 kΩ + 7.5 kΩ) = 15 kΩ in the top leg and (1 kΩ // 10 kΩ) = 909 Ω in the bottom leg.  That will produce 5.7% of the input voltage, which is 2.74 V with 48 V applied.  Apparently your mosfet is partially on with 2.74 V on its gate.

One possible option is to replace R6 with a diode so that when A is brought to ground the gate will only be at 700 mV or so.  However, a meaningful recommendation is hard to make without knowing the rest of the circuit.  Another option might be to clamp the gate to ground with a NPN transistor when you want the FET off.  There are lots of possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

If you ground A terminal R6 and R3 are in parallel. Your voltage on gate of NMOS is: 
Ug=48*(R6||R3)/(R1 + R2 + R6||R3)

If you remove R6 you will bypass R3 and gate will be on gnd potential.

Answer (score 0):

If you ground point A with an 1kOhm resistor you get 2k in parallel with 10k, which gives 5/3k=1.66k.  So the voltage divider gives 1/10 of 48V or 4.8V at the gate, which is enough to switch on the FET.

If you ground A directly you get 1k in parallel with 10k, which gives 10/11k = 909 Ohm and 2.74V at the gate (as the others have written), which is not enough to turn the FET on.